# Can i play video in Phonegap using Phonegap Build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to play video from phonegap.I am Using Phonegap build.
I search in Phonegap Doc in this [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media). But i think they only audio files play written in the docs..

So can anyone tell me its possible to play video files in phonegap using phonegap build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, phonegap just creates a native iOS app using a UIWebView so you can run your HTML code. You can access any iOS features from within the app. I'm sure the same is for Android.

Playing a video can be as simple as just opening the file locally.

For instance

```
<video controls>
<source src="yourVideo.m4v">
</video>
```

Here is a [reference from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 video tag inside a phonegap app will play video.If that is not sufficient u can alwaya play video using native code and plugin to phoneGap.